# Deriving the gradient of the loss in SNE

Tags: kullback-leibler, derivative, gradient, tsne

The objective used in SNE is the KL divergence between the two distributions and is given as

$$
E(Y) = \sum_i \sum_j p_{j|i}\log \frac{p_{j|i}}{q_{j|i}}
$$ 
and the two distributions are as follows,
$$
p_{j|i} = \frac{\exp(-(x_i - x_j)^2/2\sigma_i^2)}{\sum_{j \neq}\exp(-(x_i - x_j)^2/2\sigma_i^2)}
$$
$$
q_{j|i} = \frac{\exp(-(y_i - y_j)^2}{\sum_{j \neq}\exp(-(y_i - y_j)^2}
$$
note $p_{i|i} = 0$, $q_{i|i} = 0$

I want to obtain $\frac{\partial E}{\partial y_i}$ and is meant to be,
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial y_i} = 2\sum_j (p_{j|i} - q_{j|i} + p_{i|j} - q_{i|j}) (y_i - y_j) 
$$

I am unable to resolve the differential that I get into the above expression, this is mainly due to the denominator of $q_{i|i}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can show the beginning of your computation so that we could see where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I do not know if you already solved it, but I carried on the derivation, you can find it here: http://pages.di.unipi.it/errica/curious/ Hope this helps.

Comment: The derivation is given in appendix A of the t-SNE paper itself. See [van der Maaten and Hinton (2008). Visualizing Data using t-SNE](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v9/vandermaaten08a.html).

Comment: Derivations of SNE and t-SNE can be found [here](http://pages.di.unipi.it/errica/assets/files/sne_tsne.pdf). Unfortunately I am not able to rewrite the derivation here. Hope this helps and does not get moved to comments again, since it is an answer.

Comment: The page has been moved. The updated page is: https://diningphil.github.io/media/sne_tsne.pdf